# Receiving unexpected JSONRPC requests on my website

Tags: json-rpc

I have a production website (nothing about blockchain or related) and I a received hundreds of POST request to "/" with these params.
Obviously my server raise an error because it doesn't know how to handle it, but i am curious. What are these request? Is it something bad?

POST "/"

```
 {
      "id" => 0,
      "jsonrpc" => "2.0",
      "method" => "eth_blockNumber"
    }
```

POST "/"

```
{
  "jsonrpc" => "2.0",
  "id" => 1,
  "method" => "eth_getBlockByNumber",
  "params" => [
    "0x0",
    false
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Those look like HTTP requests to an Ethereum Node. Perhaps someone has posted your server URL as that of an Ethereum Node.

Answer (score 1):

To quickly answer the question, it does not seem to be something bad.

The second request seem to be requesting [block data based on its number .](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getblockbynumber)

I am not sure for the first. It seems to be requesting the [latest block number of the chain.](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_blocknumber)